# Electron-updater: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setClosable')

Tags: electron, electron-builder, electron-updater

After updating the libraries I am unable to update my app from a generic provider. Electron locates the update on GitHub, but stops thereafter with the following message:

[image]

```
21:26.389] [info] App starting...
:
1:28.518] [info] controllando se ci sono aggiomnamenti..
28.518] [info] Checking for update
21
30.1561 (info] Found vereion 2.1.7 (url: ------2.1.7-mac.zip, I -2.1.7.dng)
21:32.0331 [error] Error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setclosable')
  at MacUpdater.<anonymous> /Applications/.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/updater.js:88:7)
  at MacUpdater.emit (nodetevents:513:28)
  at MacUpdater.onUpdateAvailable (/Applications/.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/electron-updater/out/AppUpdater.js:337:14)
  at MacUpdater.docheekForUpdates (/Applications/.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node modules/electron-updater/out/AppUpdater.js:323:14]
  at procese.processTicksAndRejections (nodesinternal/process/task_queues:95:5)
11:21:32.0341 [info] errore durante 9li aggiornamenti.:
[node:15065) UnhendledPromiseReiection₩arning: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'webContents')
  at diepatch (/Applicetions/_app/Contents/Resources/app.asax/updater.js:23:7)
  at MacUpdater.<anonymous> (/Applications/.app/Contents/Resources/app.asax/updater.js:94:3)
  at MacUpdater.emit (nodetevente:526:35)
  at /Applications/  app/Contents/Resources/app.asax/node_modules/electzon-updater/out/AppUpdater.js:196:18
  at procese.processTickeAndRejections (nodesinternal/process/task,queues:95:5)
(Use `Laore =-trace-worninge` to show where the warning was created)
(node:16065) UnhandledPromiseRejectionMorning: Unhandled promise rejection. This exror originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by zejecting 0 Promiee which was not handled with .catchf). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag "-unhandled-rejectiong=strict' (see httpe://nodejs.org/opi/cli.html#cli_ unhandled_ rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
```

As follow the libraries versions:

- electron": "^23.1.2",
- electron-builder": "^23.6.0",
- electron-packager": "^13.1.1",
- electron-reload": "^1.4.0",
- electron-updater": "^5.0.0",
- electron-winstaller": "^3.0.4",
- standard": "^17.0.0"

updater.js

```js
const electron = require('electron')
const path = require('path')
const {app, dialog, BrowserWindow, ipcMain} = electron
const log = require('electron-log')
const {autoUpdater} = require('electron-updater')

let win;
autoUpdater.autoDownload = false
autoUpdater.logger = log
autoUpdater.logger.transports.file.level = 'info'


autoUpdater.setFeedURL({
   provider: 'github',
   token: '',
   owner: '',
   repo: '',
   vPrefixedTagName: true,
   private: true
})

const dispatch = (data) => {
  win.webContents.send('message', data)
}

const createDefaultWindow = () => {
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    icon: path.join(__dirname, '/resources/icons/logo.png'),
    width:600,
    height: 300
  })

  win.on('closed', () => {
    win = null
  })
  win.setMenu(null);
  win.setClosable(false);
  win.loadFile('electronMessage/index.html')
  return win
}


app.on('ready', () => {
  log.info('controllando se ci sono aggiornamenti..')
  autoUpdater.checkForUpdates()
})

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  app.quit()
})



autoUpdater.on('update-available', (info) => {

 dialog.showMessageBox({
    type: 'info',
    title: 'Sono disponibili nuovi aggiornamenti',
    message: 'L\'applicazione verrà aggiornata in automatico.',
    buttons: ['Ok']
  }, (buttonIndex) => {
    if (buttonIndex === 0) {
      createDefaultWindow()
      win.webContents.on('did-finish-load', () => {
        win.webContents.send('version', app.getVersion())
      })
        autoUpdater.downloadUpdate()
    }
  })
  win.setClosable(false);
})


autoUpdater.on('error', (err) => {
  log.info('errore durante gli aggiornamenti..')
  dispatch('Si è verificato un errore durante il download degli aggiornamenti:  ' + err);
  win.setClosable(true);
})

autoUpdater.on('download-progress', (progressObj) => {
    let log_message ='';
    log_message = log_message +  "Velocita\' scaricamento: " + progressObj.bytesPerSecond;
    log_message = log_message + ' - Scaricati ' + progressObj.transferred + " di " + progressObj.total + '\n';
    let infoLoad =  Math.round(progressObj.percent) + '%';
    win.webContents.send('info-speed', log_message)
    win.webContents.send('info-load', infoLoad)
    win.webContents.send('download-progress', progressObj.percent)
    win.setProgressBar(progressObj.percent);

})

autoUpdater.on('update-downloaded', (info) => {
  log.info('aggiornamenti scaricati..')
  win.setClosable(true);
  win.close();
  dialog.showMessageBox({
    type: 'info',
    title: 'Installazione',
    message: 'Aggiornamenti scaricati, l\'applicazione verrà riavviata...',
    buttons: ['Ok']
  }, (buttonIndex) => {
    if (buttonIndex === 0) {
       setImmediate(() => {
        app.removeAllListeners("window-all-closed")
        autoUpdater.quitAndInstall(false)
      })
    }
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your BrowserWindow "win" is not created yet.

You need to create window BEFORE the `autoUpdater.checkForUpdates()`

Try this way:

```js
// updater.js
const restoreOrCreateWindow = async () => {
  let window = BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().find(w => !w.isDestroyed())

  if (window === undefined)
    window = await createDefaultWindow()

  if (window.isMinimized())
    window.restore()

  window.focus()

  return window
}

app.on('ready', async () => {
  log.info('controllando se ci sono aggiornamenti..')
  await restoreOrCreateWindow()
  autoUpdater.checkForUpdates()
})
```